# Debian : Iptables rule not staying persistent, getting deleted in sometime

Tags: debian, iptables, nagios

I am working on a Debian stable system and we want to add a rule to allow access for Nagios. Unfortunately, the rule is automatically getting deleted after some time. We are unable to find out what's going wrong. Any ideas?
I have installed iptables-persistent package already.

Rule :

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 5666 -j ACCEPT
```

Initially it shows with the following command, but then it suddenly disappears :

```
iptables -S | grep 5666
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you investigated how iptables-persistent works?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : Yes, I already see the rules in /etc/iptables/v4, the error I can think of is there is no service iptables-persistent found to start. Thank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg Add your rule to the file /etc/iptables/rules.v4 and restart netfilter-persistent service

Comment: @ibrahim : Tried already, not working.

Comment: @ibrahim : I already had the rule in rules.v4...and still did a netfilter-persistent restart. The rule has now gone.

Comment: Create a network script as described here : [Making Changes permanent](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables) .

Comment: @GAD3R : Sorry for the late reply. Tried that, and few other approaches today. I am not experiencing a problem after reboot. The rule just seems to disappear after some time. When I give iptables -S | grep 5666 after some time, I don't see the rule.